# Magento product not show on frontend after import

Tags: magento-1.7

In magento i have imported products, it imported successfully but it is not showing in front-end. And when open product in admin and save without changing anything then it shows in front-end. What i made mistake while importing ?
Please any body can tell me ? Thanks